# Can I disable Bonding on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Just to get things straight.

**Pairing** is the exchange of temporary encryption keys, which establishes an encrypted connection.

**Bonding** occurs after pairing, and is the exchange of long term encryption keys so that the pairing process does not have to be repeated every time.

Im interested in having an encrypted connection, but I don't want to end with a huge list of saved devices on my phone. After watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84GW3IF1jUI), I know it is possible, I just need to know how to do it on my Raspberry Pi. Currently, I am running a GATT server based on [this](https://github.com/PunchThrough/espresso-ble) repo, which comes the article linked below:

- [Creating a BLE Peripheral with BlueZ](https://punchthrough.com/creating-a-ble-peripheral-with-bluez/)

Comment: Might be better asked on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @spikey_richie Noted. Thanks!